# how can I add free days in Authorize.net ARB monthly subscription?

Tags: payment, subscription, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am using **authorize.net** *ARB monthly subscription* method, that is running fine.

I have a task to give first 7-Days free, and process payment after 7-Days.

That means if client does not want to continue subscription within 7-Days he can cancel his subscription and payment will not get deducted from his account.

I have looked into PDF documentation file and nothing can be found, please guide me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's an argument called `startDate` in the XML request to create the subscription. If you set that to seven days in the future, the payment will not be processed until then. In the mean time, a subscription will still be created so you can cancel it early to avoid the payment entirely.

You should be able to find this in the documentation under `ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest`. In my copy of the pdf (which is a little bit old so it might be different now), `startDate` is documented on page 10 and page 5 mentions:

> ARB subscriptions do not process transactions in real-time. A successful creation of an ARB
>   subscription transaction is not an indicator that the subscription payments that process through your
>   account will be successful. ARB subscription transactions process at approximately 2am PST on
>   their scheduled payment dates. **This means that the first scheduled transaction will not be sent to the
>   customer's bank for authorization until approximately 2am PST on the start date that you specify
>   upon creating the subscription in your account.** If you create a subscription with a start date that
>   equals the creation date, the first scheduled payment will not process until after 2am the following
>   day. If you wish to validate your customer's payment information before creating their subscription
>   in your account, please use one of the real-time transaction processing methods, such as the AIM
>   (Advanced Integration Method).

The bolded section is important.